vs code setting to load env file for jupyter notebook
When running the python debugger I can use  "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/env"
in my settings.json file to set environmental variables when using the debugger.
How do I use these project env files in jupyter notebooks? I would like a solution that works for all notebooks and projects without having to modify the underlying notebooks. I see other answers recommend using the dotfile package but that requires a package be added to environments just so they work in vs code which isn't ideal.
I see there is an option I can add to settings.json called "jupyter.runStartupCommands" where I can run some python code. Is there a way to get ${workspaceFolder} to resolve here so I can load the file?


"envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/env"

This line of setting only takes effect in debug mode and interactive windows mode. When you use jupyter, it will not take effect. Currently, jupyter does not support directly selecting the env file in the settings to obtain additional environment variables.
You could create a new python file named load_env.py:
import os

def load_env():
    env_file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '.vscode/env')
    with open(env_file_path, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            name, value = line.strip().split('=', 1)
            os.environ[name] = value

load_env()

Then in your settings.json, add the following to jupyter.runStartupCommands:
"jupyter.runStartupCommands": "%run ./load_env.py"

Of course, you can also submit relevant feature requests to developers in jupyter's github repository and vote for it.

%run ${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/env does not resolve $workspaceFolder.  I can use a relative path but that wont work for files in lower level directories of the workspace folder

@guest I updated my answer, can this solve your issue?

This still doesnt work for anything not in the top level of the workspace directory. I have a solution already similar to this but it seems the easiest thing is if  ${workspaceFolder} is exposed to the user. Im not sure if that is something I would need to ask the vscode-jupyter maintainers to implement or if it needs to be requested of the  vscode maintainers to make the env variable avalible to all plugins
